# A little help on geometric description of $\Bbb R^2$ in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I just started studying vectors in linear algebra, and I didn't understand the idea of the geometric description of a vector.

**Why do we treat the vector entries as coordinates?**

As far as I understand, the entries of a column vector are the coefficients of the same variable of different equations. If I'm right on the previous sentence then why do we use them as a coordinate $(x,y)$ (for $\Bbb R^2$) and why do we treat them as different entries?

My English is poor, so if you didn't understand me let me try it with an example.

Let's say there are two equations with two variables.

$$\begin{align}
2x + 3y &= 4 \\
x + 5y &= 15 
\end{align}$$

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 
2 & 3 &|& 4 \\
1 & 5 &|& 15 
\end{matrix}\right]$$

If I take $(2, 1)$ as a column vector, $2$ is a run and $1$ is a rise. This is what I didn't understand as far as $2$ and $1$ are the same $x$ value, why do we use one as a run and the other as a rise?

Thank you.

correction
 i just changed the 2nd entire from 1 to 3 just to make it more clear and understandable

Comment: The idea of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is independent of the idea of linear systems.

Comment: You're example is confusing; there are two $1$s in that matrix

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks, i edit it and i hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea you're struggling with here is that of matrix multiplication.

If we were to solve your system of equations using matrix multiplication, we'd start with the equality
$$
\pmatrix{2&3\\1&5} \pmatrix{x\\y} = \pmatrix{4\\15}
$$
From this point alone, it's difficult to see the meaning of the column vectors of a matrix.  However, notice that
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{2&3\\1&5} \pmatrix{x\\y} &= 
\pmatrix{2&3\\1&5} \left[x\pmatrix{1\\0} + y\pmatrix{0\\1}\right] 
\\&=
x\pmatrix{2&3\\1&5}\pmatrix{1\\0} + y\pmatrix{2&3\\1&5}\pmatrix{0\\1}
\\&=
x\pmatrix{2\\1} + y\pmatrix{3\\5}
\end{align}

Comment: See my latest edit.  You had multiplied the matrices incorrectly